# how to change the image when the hyperlink which is clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This will run when the page loads

```
<TD width=115 >
    <a href="#" onclick="some functions"> Expand All</a>
</TD>

<TD align=left>
    <a href="#"><IMG id="img1" border=0 alt="" src="expand.png">12345 </a>
</TD>
```

By default, expand.png image will be displayed with 12345..
My question is If I click expand all link, I need to change the image "expand.png" to "collapse.png"..Is it possible in javascript?

Comment: <B HREF?> - Think you've muddled up your tags...

Comment: _"Is it possible in javascript?"_. Of course it is; what have you tried?

Comment: sorry..changed to <a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will solve your issue.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('img1').src='collapse.png'">Expand All</a>
 <a href="#"><IMG id="img1" border=0 alt="" src="expand.png">12345</a>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zJ85X/

Answer (score 4):

Does it need to be pure JS?

Jquery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     $('#withImage').attr('src', 'collapse.png');
});
```

You would have to give the TD's a class or an ID

pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('button').onClick(runFunction());

function runFunction(){
   document.getElementById('withImage').src = 'collapse.png';
}
```

First line of code is telling the script that when a tag with the id "button" (

In the function you are telling the script that the tag with id "withImage" should change its attribute "src" to be 'collapse.png'.

Comment: he says in javascript not in jquery

Comment: can I use image id img1 that I mentioned in my code instead of td?

Comment: @user3107196 Yes you can.

Comment: if it is possible in jquery, please share the code with jsfiddle

Comment: document.getElementByID('button').onClick(runFunction());

this would be a way of doing it in pure JS

Comment: can u please explain in detail as an answer?

Comment: Update my answer, i cant really be more specific than that. Maybe you should try out some beginner courses for javascript, just to get the hang of the basics.

Comment: @Slugge Mind you, a small but important typo it's `document.getElementById`, not `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<TD width=115 >
     <a href="#" onclick="expand()"> Expand All</a>
</TD>
<TD align=left>
     <a href="#"><IMG id="img1" border=0 alt="" src="expand.png">12345 </a>
</TD>
<script>
     function expand(){
          $('#img1').attr('src','collapse.png');
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code to your function of Expand All, if its Jquery

```
$('#img1').attr('src', 'collapse.png');
```